# Cómo leer este json

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, http-get, xmlhttprequest

Al hacer la siguiente petición:

```js
$.ajax({

url: "...",
type: "GET",

sucess: function(response) {

console.log(response);

}


});
```

Me da como resultado:

```js
/*O_o*/ 
google.visualization.Query.setResponse({"version":"0.6","reqId":"0","status":"ok","sig":"2146391061","table":{"cols":[{"id":"A","label":"Marca temporal","type":"datetime","pattern":"d/MM/yyyy H:mm:ss"},{"id":"B","label":"Purple #1","type":"string"},{"id":"C","label":"Purple #2","type":"string"}],"rows":[{"c":[{"v":"Date(2022,5,25,1,23,20)","f":"25/06/2022 1:23:21"},{"v":"blue"},{"v":"yellow"}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(2022,5,25,2,8,5)","f":"25/06/2022 2:08:05"},{"v":"red"},{"v":"black"}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(2022,5,25,2,8,13)","f":"25/06/2022 2:08:13"},{"v":"tomato"},{"v":"gray"}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(2022,5,25,2,8,21)","f":"25/06/2022 2:08:22"},{"v":"green"},{"v":"pink"}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(2022,5,25,2,8,55)","f":"25/06/2022 2:08:55"},{"v":"orange"},{"v":"turqoise"}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(2022,5,25,2,9,28)","f":"25/06/2022 2:09:29"},{"v":"violet"},{"v":"purple"}]}],"parsedNumHeaders":1}});
```

Pero no logro leerlo incluso usando *JSON.parse()*

Comment: Prueba agregando esto debajo de la linea del GET:  `headers: {"X-DataSource-Auth":""},` está sacado de [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60014207/10382744) y de [aqui](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/dev/implementing_data_source#security-considerations)

Answer (score 2):

La respuesta que estás recibiendo no es un `Json`, así que hay que transformarlo en uno.

Por ejemplo podrías hacer lo siguiente:

```
    response = response.replace(/(^\/\*O_o\*\/([\s\S]*[\n\r]*)google\.visualization\.Query\.setResponse\(|\);$)/g,'');

    responseJSON = JSON.parse(response);
```

Y así en `responseJSON` tendrías lo que buscas.

Comment: Eso que pone `/*O_o*/` también lo tendria que eliminar y con tu solución no lo haces

Comment: Hola @masterguru, lo he actualizado para que tenga en cuenta también el `/*O_o*/`

Comment: Pues aún no funciona. Míralo tu mismo aquí: https://jsfiddle.net/mhzxy7gn/  (debes tener en cuenta el salto de linea supongo)

Comment: Ahora si :-)  Saludos!

Comment: Cómo no tengo claro si la respuesta le llega con retorno de carro, espacio o espacios, he añadido `([\s\S]*[\n\r]*)`  al regex para que tenga en cuenta las distintas posibilidades. ;-)